# why does mystring.split(" ").append("foo") returns nothing?

Tags: python, string, list, python-3.x

I have a variable that store a prompt which look like this : `(path>in>the>cli)`
I want to update it to have `(path>in>the>cli>foo)` and came with this :

```
 prompt = ">".join(prompt.replace(")","").split(">").append('foo')) + ")"
```

But I have a type error because `prompt.replace(")","").split(">").append('foo')` return `None`

Why does it return `None` instead of `['(path', 'in', 'the', 'cli', 'foo']` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`append()` modifies a list "in-place" and returns `None`:

```
>>> print(prompt.replace(")","").split(">").append('foo'))
None
```

You need to append the item to the list via `+`:

```
>>> ">".join(prompt.replace(")","").split(">") + ['foo']) + ")"
'(path>in>the>cli>foo)'
```

Comment: Worth noting that `+=` doesn't append, it concatenates a list on to the end of the given list.

Comment: @Isaac thanks, yeah, it basically doesn't modify the list in place, makes a new one.

Answer (score 3):

`list.append` always returns None, and not the list. This is deliberate, since it emphasises that append mutates the list. From [the docs](http://docs.python.org/3.4/tutorial/datastructures.html):

> You might have noticed that methods like insert, remove or sort that
>   modify the list have no return value printed – they return None. 
>   This is a design principle for all mutable data structures in Python.

So, you need to do this as three lines:

```
items = prompt.replace(")","").split(">")
items.append('foo')
prompt = '>'.join(items)
```

Answer (score 1):

The single most important two words for a beginning (in a new language or new altogether!) software engineer would probably be "try it!". When you have such a lovely REPLy sort of thing as with Python, you really should give it a try.

```
>>> a = []
>>> a.append(1)
>>> a
[1]
```

You can concatenate a list on, in place, with `+`, like so:

```
>>> a + [1]
[1, 1]
```

Or you can store the list in an intermediate variable, and then append to it with `append`, which actually appends to the list in place, and returns `None`.